# Prove that there is NO monomorphism of $\mathbb{Z_{6}}$ in $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove that there is NO monomorphism of $\mathbb{Z_{6}}$ in $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$ ($\mathbb{Z_{6}}$ and $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$ are rings).

Let $f: \mathbb{Z_{6}} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_{11}}$ be a homomorphism. If $f$ is injective, that is, it is a one-to-one function, then $f$ is said to be a monomorphism.

I'm trying to find a contradiction but can't find it for this test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ is a field ($11$ is prime) so it has no zero divisors. The image of any ring homomorphism is a subring. Since $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ has zero divisors, its image has them too. Therefore only zero homomorphism is possible.

Another approach: $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ are additive groups. The image of a group under any homomorphism is a subgroup. By Lagrange's theorem its order divides the order of an ambient group. But $11$ is prime.