# Find the quotient ring $T_{2}(\mathbb{Z_{4}})/I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $T_{2}(\mathbb{Z_{4}})= \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}:a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z_{4}}\right\}$ be the ring of all upper triangular matrices on $\mathbb{Z_{4}}$.
>
> Prove that $I =\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}0&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}: b,c \in \mathbb{Z_{4}}\right\}$ is an ideal of $T_{2}(\mathbb{Z_{4}})$. Find the quotient ring $T_{2}(\mathbb{Z_{4}})/I$.

I already have proof that $I$ is an ideal of $T_{2}(\mathbb{Z_{4}})$. Could someone help me find the quotient ring?

Comment: I don't know why you wrote your whole post in italics but I think it's distracting a hard to read. Hence I've removed it (here and on your [last post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008679/prove-that-there-is-no-monomorphism-of-mathbbz-6-in-mathbbz-11) a few minutes ago).

Comment: @mrtaurho I'm sorry, it was for aesthetics only

Comment: I don't think "Find the quotient ring" is a meaningful question. The quotient ring is a perfectly well-defined object as-is, but presumably you want to find some other well-known ring it is isomorphic to. To that end, can you come up with a ring homomorphism from $T_2(\mathbb{Z}_4)$ to some other ring such that the kernel is precisely $I$? Then apply the isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Consider the following ring homomorphism $f: T_2 (\Bbb Z_4) \to \Bbb Z_4$ defined by
$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix} \mapsto a$$
Show that this is an onto ring homomorphism and show that $I= \ker f$.

Then apply the first isomorphism theorem to get
$$T_2 (\Bbb Z_4) / I  \cong \Bbb Z_4$$